# Компиляция gdbserver под mips

Tags: linux, gdb, кросс-компиляция

При попытке скомпилировать gdbserver под платформу mips, при вызове make сборка вылетает с ошибкой:

```
linux-mips-low.c:107: error: 'FPC_CSR' was not declared in this scope 
linux-mips-low.c:107: error: 'FPC_EIR' was not declared in this scope 
Makefile:263: recipe for target 'linux-mips-low.o' failed
make: *** [linux-mips-low.o] Error 1
```

Использую компилятор `linux-mips-gnu-gcc`, команда конфигурации: `./configure --host=mips-linux-gnu -CC=mips-linux-gnu-gcc -RANLIB=mips-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib`

Но стоит только сделать make, как через некоторое время появляется эта ошибка. Как разобраться, какие либы нужно поставить или что нужно сделать? В гугле нет ответа на подобный вопрос...

Comment: какие версии всего (gdb, gcc, libc)? у меня на crossdev'овском тулчейне gdb-8.1 собрался чистенько с полпинка... а вот 7.9 тоже капризничал и ругался на конфликт определений функций из того же `linux-mips-low.c` и `proc_service.h`... ЗЫ: к проблеме не относится, но `CC` и `RANLIB` вручную указывать избыточно, а `ranlib` по идее ещё и неверно задан...

Comment: `gdb-8.1` `gcc version 7.2.0`  почему неверно ранлиб задан, я проверял `omenus@Evil:~/gdb-8.1/gdb$ mips-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib -v
GNU ranlib (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.29.1
` А если не указывать в ручную то он не всегда корректно поподает в `Makefile`

Comment: гмм... макросы должны быть объявлены в `<asm/ptrace.h>` — это часть kernel-headers и на вскидку они там очень давно, так что от версии это не должно зависеть... может по какой-то причине подтянулся `<asm/ptrace.h>` из хостовой системы? но почему тогда нет ругани на FPR_BASE?.. по поводу ranlib — мой косяк, думал, что `-gcc` —  ошибка копипасты... ЗЫ: но минусы перед `CC` и `RANLIB` всё равно лишние...

Comment: На это тоже ругается, там вывод большой. Ругается на все регистры указанные в 'linux-mips-low.c'

Comment: Ага....Я так понимаю что lunux-headers для mips обязателен к установке? linux-libc-dev-mips-cross пойдёт? Не хотелось бы собирать что-то для того чтобы собрать ещё что то.

Comment: да,  конечно, это часть тулчейна... странно, что он вообще без них сконфигурировался... по названию пакета — не уверен, я не особо ориентируюсь в пакетных дистрах, наверное он, но я бы всё же поискал что-то вроде `linux[-kernel]-headers-mips*`...

Comment: Есть такой `linux-libc-dev-mips-cross самой новой версии (4.10.0-14.16cross1)`

Comment: Используйте Buildroot — там всё уже в дистрибутиве.

Comment: Это я знаю, но мне не совсем это подходит, если я правильно понимаю принцип работы buildroot. Да и собирать фс ради одного gdbserver затратно по времени. Пробовал crosstool-ng, собирается вся 7 ветка gdb, а 8 не как не хочет. Ругается на C++ библиотеки в тулчейне.